# Can my laptop run ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

Recently I bought a [Lenovo Thinkpad L380](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-l/ThinkPad-L380/p/22TP2TBL38020M5) and was wondering if I will be able to dualboot it with Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

- 8GB RAM,
- 256 SSD,
- Intel i5 8350U

Comment: according to the wiki here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements you should be fine

Comment: Why not try it on your actual hardware?  (*Can my laptop run ubuntu*) https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0  Yes you can dualboot, but the complexity of dual booting can vary on devices in my experience and I don't know your device; enterprise/business grade are usually easier than consumer*

Comment: Usually the best way to check is trying ubuntu live on the downloaded ISO that you burn to a USB stick.  Once you find everything is working well, then you can decide to install it.

Comment: Please ask about problems related to installing and using Ubuntu with issues you actually face. "Can my laptop run ubuntu?" Ubuntu is free, so why don't you just install it and see where you strand.

Answer (score 0):

almost every windows laptop can run ubuntu.

and if i take a look at your specs i am really sure it can.

i also installed ubuntu on my windows laptop and i was great, but if you want to install another distro than ubuntu then i suggest to install an ubuntu-based distro

but ubuntu is amazing for people who want to switch from windows to ubuntu